# tracing use RUST_LOG env var and ignore other crates

Tags: logging, rust, rust-tracing

I have a binary application (with the functionality broken out into a lib.rs) for which I am trying to set up tracing. The behaviour I am trying to achieve is:

- Log events to stdout.
- Events from anywhere that is not my crate should always be ignored.
- Nothing should be logged if `RUST_LOG` is not set, otherwise only log to the level set by `RUST_LOG`.

I believe that a combination of:

```rust
tracing_subscriber::fmt()
    .with_env_filter(EnvFilter::new("my_crate"))
    .init();
```

and

```rust
tracing_subscriber::fmt()
    .with_env_filter(EnvFilter::from_default_env())
    .init();
```

Should achieve what I am looking for, but I can't work out how to combine these. I tried the below but that didn't work.

```rust
tracing_subscriber::fmt()
    .with_env_filter(
        EnvFilter::from_default_env()
            .add_directive(Directive::from_str("my_crate").unwrap()),
    )
    .init();
```

Comment: `if std::env::var("RUST_LOG").is_ok() { tracing_subscriber::fmt().with_env_filter(EnvFilter::new("my_crate")).init(); }`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that is an improvement over what I have currently, but it won't abide by the RUST_LOG value, it just logs all levels if any value is set.

Comment: I thought this is what you want. So: do you want the level (but not path) to be controlled by `RUST_LOG`? What about: `if let Ok(level) = std::env::var("RUST_LOG") { tracing_subscriber::fmt().with_env_filter(EnvFilter::new(&format!("my_crate={level}"))).init(); }`?

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much! If you add it as an answer I'll mark it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple is better than complex:

```rust
if let Ok(level) = std::env::var("RUST_LOG") {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter(EnvFilter::new(&format!("my_crate={level}")))
        .init();
}
```

You know what, let's be a bit more future-proof against future crate name change:

```rust
if let Ok(level) = std::env::var("RUST_LOG") {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter(EnvFilter::new(&format!(
            "{}={level}",
            env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME").replace("-", "_"),
        )))
        .init();
}
```